# Get entire packet output instead of line by line of shell command in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am newbie in python and like to execute command and capture its output into variable.
Below code is working fine but the issue is it's giving me output line by line instead of entire packet.

I tried to find alternatives but not getting enough information from google for this specific scenario.

```
import subprocess
command='tcpdump -nqt -s 0 -A -i eth0 port 5060'
process = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
var = None
while True:
  nextline = process.stdout.readline()
  print "Output (%s)" % nextline
```

All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Well, you *are* reading the output line-by-line... you can also do `output = process.stdout.read()`

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for reply. I already tried before but it's not giving me any output.

Comment: That's probably because `tcpdump` keeps running... You cannot have something that keeps running forever and expect to be able to read the whole output without blocking. It's really unclear what you want to obtain as output...

Comment: @Bakuriu I am expecting tcpdump needs to be run forever until it's block manually and parallel also read output of it wihtout blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Popen.communicate() method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
import subprocess
command='tcpdump -nqt -s 0 -A -i eth0 port 5060'
process = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
var,stde = process.communicate()
print var
print stde #this print stderrror value.
```